# WPF MVVM updating property in viewmodel when something changes in other viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I need to update the `Language` property in `MyVM1` and `MyVM2` when the `Language` property changes in `LanguageVM` (see image).

[image]

Comment: you can define a singleton property for Language in BaseVm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of approaches to accomplish this. You can define an **[event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea.aspx)** in your **LanguageProvider** class. If you can have only one **LanguageProvider** object, you can mark the event as **static**, so you do not need to pass reference to **LanguageProvider** to **YoursVM** classes.

```
public static class LanguageProvider
{
    private Language currentLanguage = Language.DefaultLanguage;
    public delegate void LanguageChangedEventHandler(object sender, LanguageChangedEventArgs e);

    public static event LanguageChangedEventHandler LanguageChanged;
    public static void SetLanguage(string langId)
    {
        var oldLang = currentLanguage;
        currentLanguage = new Language(langId);
        if (LanguageChangedEventHandler != null)
        {
            LanguageChangedEventHandler(null, new LanguageChangedEventArgs(oldLangId:oldLang, newLang:currentLanguage)); 
        }
    }         
}
```

And in your **BaseVM** base constructor:

```
public BaseVM()
{
    ...
    LanguageProvider.LanguageChanged += OnLanguageChanged;
    ...
}

private void OnLanguageChanged(object sender, LanguageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Language = e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: Your code is probably not tested (contains some errors in the LanguageProvider) but it is good enough to get the idea, thanks.

Comment: Can be done like that, but this kind of beats the purpose of MVVM as it makes the ViewModel (or all ViewModel since it's inside the BaseVM class) dependent on LanguageProvider. Better approach would be an event aggregator which comes with some MVVM Frameworks and then get it via ServiceLocator (Better: Use Dependency Injection)

Comment: MVVM is for separating Presentation and Model layers. The dependency you are talking about is the module dependency, which can be broken using IoC containers, like Unity or MEF containers.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer interface based programming and readability of dependencies. See below

Code is not compiled or tested and only given to convey the idea.

Your viewmodels are "language aware". Create an interface for this functionality

```
public interface ILanguageAware
{
   void ChangeLanguage(string lang);
}
```

implement the interface

```
public class MyVM1:ILanguageAware
{
  public void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
  {
    //do the language change tasks
  }
}
```

Your provider can have the capability to keep the language aware objects

```
public interface ILanguageProvider
{
   void AddLanguageAwareObject(ILanguageAware langawareobj) ;

   void RemoveLanguageAwareObject(ILanguageAware langawareobj) ;
}
```

Your viewmodels can add themselves the language provider

```
public MyVM1:ILanguageAware
{
  ILanguageProvider _langprovider =null;

  public MyVM1(ILanguageProvider provider)
  {
    _langprovider = provider;
    _langprovider.AddLanguageAwareObject(this);
  }

}
```

Implement the provider

```
public class LanguageProvider:ILanguageProvider
{
  List<ILanguageAware> _langawarelist = new List<ILanguageAware>();

  void AddLanguageAwareObject(ILanguageAware langawareobj) 
  {
   _langawarelist .Add(langawareobj);
  }

  public void SetLanguage(string lang)
  {
  _langawarelist .foreach(x=>x.ChangeLanguage(lang);

  }    

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, the answer of stukselbax works already fine for my situation.